# Add Custom User Agents to Modsecurity OWASP Rule in Plesk

Tags: plesk, mod-security

I always make requests with an .NET Application to my Server and this is all working fine as long as I define a "normal" user agent like:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
```

but if I define my own like

```
"TestProgram/121521 (Testtest)"
```

it is blocking my data.

Does someone know how to add a custom rule to modsecurity where I can add my custom user agent so it dont gets blocked anymore?

Comment: Which rule blocks the request with your UA header? You can find it in the debug.log or error.log of your http daemon.

Comment: I can't look now because the program is running and all users are online but normally in the Header Check block.

Comment: There are so many rules in phase:1 (where the engine checks the headers), so it would be know the exact rule id. You can check it without modify of your code, just use curl: `curl -v -H 'User-Agent: TestProgram/121521 (Testtest)' 'http://your.app.url'`, and see your logs.

Comment: Nope the problem is I have to activate the rule set for this and then I will get thousands of error within minutes.

Comment: @airween http://prntscr.com/px9kvz that is the error

Answer (score 0):

Based on your captured screenshot, the problem is not your User-Agent, but the missing 'Accept' header from your request.

Try this:

`curl -v -H 'User-Agent: TestProgram/121521 (Testtest)' -H 'Accept: */*' 'http://your.app.url'`

Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you I tried this but if I run your command in ssh I only get the code of my website in the console. So where should I add your code (note that I make my requests from a windows program). And then my next problem is that the "121521" always gets changed because thats the version number

Comment: Right, but if you can run the `curl`, and you can pass the `-H 'Foo: Bar'` argument, why don't you pass an another? :)